# How to write the output to a file, the name of which is passed as a second parameter?

Tags: python

```
def generate_daily_totals(input_filename, output_filename):
    """result in the creation of a file blahout.txt containing the two lines"""

    with open(input_filename, 'r') as reader, open(output_filename, 'w') as writer: #updated


        for line in reader: #updated   
            pieces = line.split(',')

            date = pieces[0]

            rainfall = pieces[1:] #each data in a line 

            total_rainfall = 0
            for data in rainfall:

                pure_data = data.rstrip()
                total_rainfall = total_rainfall + float(pure_data)


            writer.write(date + "=" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_rainfall) + '\n') #updated
            #print(date, "=", '{:.2f}'.format(total_rainfall)) #two decimal point format, 
generate_daily_totals('data60.txt', 'totals60.txt')
checker = open('totals60.txt')
print(checker.read())
checker.close()
```

By reading a file, the original program runs well but I was required to convert it by writing the file. I am confused as the write method applies to string only so does that mean only the print section can be replaced by write method? This is the first time I am trying to use the write method. Thanks!

EDIT: the above codes have been updated based on the blhsing instruction which helped a lot! But still not running well as the for loop which gets skipped for some reason. Proper suggestions would be appreciated!

```
expected output:
2006-04-10 = 1399.46
2006-04-11 = 2822.36
2006-04-12 = 2803.81
2006-04-13 = 1622.71
2006-04-14 = 3119.60
2006-04-15 = 2256.14
2006-04-16 = 3120.05
2006-04-20 = 1488.00
```

Comment: Due to my original with statement processing, input file contect is erased, that is the reason by the loop got skipped. I think all my problems were solved! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open both the input file for reading, and the output file for writing, so change:

```
with open(input_filename, 'w') as writer:
    for line in writer: # error not readable
```

to:

```
with open(input_filename, 'r') as reader, open(output_filename, 'w') as writer:
    for line in reader:
```

Also, unlike the `print` function, the `write` method of a file object does not automatically add a trailing newline character to the output, so you would have to add it on your own.

Change:

```
writer.write(date + "=" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_rainfall))
```

to:

```
writer.write(date + "=" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_rainfall) + '\n')
```

or you can use `print` with the outputting file object specified as the `file` argument:

```
print(date, "=", '{:.2f}'.format(total_rainfall), file=writer)
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, I did follow your guidance but after running line "with open(input_filename, 'r') as reader, open(output_filename, 'w') as writer:" the program just skipped to the function call in line 23 and till the end. I am wondering any other problems with my original codes?

Comment: Thanks again no further question about this instruction!

Comment: If it didn't do anything it sounds like the input file is empty.